# Lower frame is not rendered in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am trying to create a basic window with tkinter (python3), the window should have a screenshot on the top and on the bottom there should be a text box and a button.
This is the code I wrote

```py
    from tkinter import Frame, TOP, BOTTOM, LEFT, RIGHT
    from tkinter import Tk, Entry, Label, Button

    from PIL import ImageGrab
    from PIL.ImageTk import PhotoImage

    curr_image = ImageGrab.grab()

    image_root_window = Tk()

    # The screenshot image
    image_frame = Frame(image_root_window)
    image_display = PhotoImage(curr_image)
    image_label = Label(image_frame, image=image_display)
    image_label.pack()
    image_frame.pack(side=TOP)

    # The reward input box
    input_frame = Frame(image_root_window)
    reward_input_box = Entry(input_frame)
    finish_btn = Button(input_frame, text="next", command=None)
    reward_input_box.pack(side=LEFT)
    reward_input_box.focus()
    finish_btn.pack(side=RIGHT)
    input_frame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

    image_root_window.mainloop()
```

However when I run this all I see is the screenshot and the bottom frame (with the Entry and the Button) is no where to be found.
What is my problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, in the moment you call

```
image_frame.pack(side=TOP)
```

image_frame is going to use the full window size.
You may try giving image_frame a certain height, i.e. by using place() instead of pack().
With place you can specifie the position and dimension of an element.